# UITextView displays invisible unicode as question mark

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode

I'm experiencing with a problem, where UITextView display ZERO WIDTH `\u200d` character as question mark. Is there any option to hide or cut such control characters? Without edition of string by removing such character?